# HOW TO JOIN 2 tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have 2 tables `dbo.seat` and `dbo.booking`

`dbo.seat`

```
noSeat
------
1-2
1-3
1-4
1-8
4-2
4-3
4-4
5-1
5-2
```

`dbo.booking`

```
noBooking   |  noSeat  | statusBooked |       endTime
1002           1-4            0         2015-02-16 13:30:00.000
1003           1-4            1         2015-02-17 13:30:00.000
1004           1-8            1         2015-02-17 13:30:00.000
1005           1-2            0         2015-02-16 14:59:00.000
1006           1-3            0         2015-02-16 14:59:00.000
```

How to take `seat.noSeat` which is not booked ?

This sample show us that `seat` number 1-4 and 1-8 is booked. and I want to know what seat is available(the output is all seat.noSeat except 1-4 and 1-8) ?

Table `booking` is for booking transaction and `seat` is list of seat provided.

**UPDATE :**

`statusBooked` will automatically update to 0 when endTime is equal `CurrentTime`. it mean it's over and tell us that 1-4 is available until someone booked it again (insert method to `dbo.booking` `statusBooked` by default 1)

Comment: Use Inner Join between two table on "noseat" and add "WHERE" clause as "StatusBooked <> 1"

Comment: You have bookings that are not booking seats (statusBooked = 0) and seat 1-4 is both booked and not booked?

Comment: @JamesZ it's for status is that seat still booked or has been available. it means that seat 1-4 was booked by someone and now is booked again by someone else. 0 is available 1 is booked

Comment: @PareshJ I try this `SELECT s.noSeat FROM seat s INNER JOIN booking b ON s.noSeat = b.noSeat WHERE b.statusBooked <> 1` and the result is what is in booking table.

Comment: @azalikaEriya What do you want is still unclear. Can you update your question with expected result? That would help people here to answer.

Comment: please read 7 line from bottom @JenishRabadiya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from dbo.seat
where noseat not in (
    select noseat
    from dbo.booking
    where statusbooking = 1
)
```

Here's my guess. I can't say I really understand what "noseat" means (unless it's "number of seat")?

Comment: number of seat. yes you are right. it works. but is it oke for any case in future maybe ? @shwant00

Comment: As far as I understand it. If there's a row with statusBooking equal to 1 then that seat should be excluded from your results. That's pretty much all it does.

Comment: You should probably use an explicit select list but there must be another problem in the c# code.

Comment: It would be best to supply full error message if you still want assistance with that. It sounds like that's a separate question though.