# "not" in query syntax

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have query

```
select *from dbo.seat
where noseat not in 
(select noseat from dbo.booking where statusbooked = 1)
```

And I put it in my .aspx.cs file but it show error.

```
conn.Open();
        string sql = "select *from dbo.seatwhere noseat not in ( select noseat from dbo.booking where statusbooked = 1)";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'not'.

this is my table [open this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554473/how-to-join-2-tables-in-sql-server-2008)

what's the problem ?

Comment: The query in your code is different from the one above in the question. statusbooking  field.

Comment: you forgot space here: `dbo.seatwhere`

Comment: If the answers below solve your problem you really have to wake up seriously before posting to SO :p

Comment: @YoupTube happens to the best of us =)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid such *silly* errors (*missed space* before 1st `where`) format out your code:

```
using (SqlConection conn = new SqlConection(yourConnectionStringHere)) {
  conn.Open();

  // SQL should be readable...
  string sql = 
    @"select *
        from dbo.seat
       where noseat not in (
               select noseat 
                 from dbo.booking 
                where statusbooked = 1)";

  // All disposable instances should be properly disposed...
  using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)) {
    // All disposable instances should be properly disposed...
    using(var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
      while (dr.Read()) {
        ...
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do NOT IN without considering NULL values in the sub-select, because if there are one (or more) of them, the NOT IN is NULL, and query returns no rows at all - probably not what most people expect...

Either add IS NOT NULL to the sub-select:

```
select * from dbo.seat
where noseat not in 
(select noseat from dbo.booking
 where statusbooked = 1
   and noseat IS NOT NULL)
```

Or, use NOT EXISTS instead (which is "null safe"):

```
select * from dbo.seat s
where NOT EXISTS
(select 1 from dbo.booking b
 where statusbooked = 1
   and b.noseat = s.noseat)
```

Comment: why do you `select 1` ? I don't understand. would you mind to explain ? @jarlh

Comment: It doesn't matter what you select in an EXISTS/NOT EXISTS sub-query, it's about if a row is found or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing Space `wherenoseat`

```
string sql = "select *from dbo.seat where noseat not in ( select noseat from dbo.booking where statusbooked = 1)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add space between table name and where keyword

```
    select *from dbo.seat where noseat not in 
        ( select noseat from dbo.booking where statusbooked = 1)
```

Comment: What about a whitespace between * & from ?!

Comment: @YoupTube: It will not produce error.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to make space between * and from. (optional but always good practise to make it.)
2. space between table name and where keyword
3. statusbooked  to statusbooking or statusbooking to statusbooked.

   ```
   string sql = "select * from dbo.seat where noseat not in 
   ( select noseat from dbo.booking where statusbooked = 1)";
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Space missing:
1. tablename and noseat column.
2. between * and from

string sql = "select * from dbo.seat where noseat not in ( select noseat from dbo.booking where statusbooked = 1)";